Are materialized views a good option to access calculated data in terms of performance?
We have the following model in our Google BigQuery DB to work with large amounts of data about employees, demographics, etc.:

SRC_ tables, with automated extractions from several systems like SAP, SSFF, etc.
PPL_ tables, where we store processed data merging different sources (E.g.: PPL_Employees)
CDM_ tables, with metrics and calculated data (E.g.: gender distribution, salary distributions, etc.)

We have an internal debate about the approach for CDM_ tables, with two opinions:

Create CDM as tables, with stored procedures that we will execute every week to calculate all the data. Better performance, harder to maintain.
Create CDM as Materialized views, enabling "auto-refresh" with a simpler mechanism. Simpler way, doubts about performance.

Are materialized views a good option to access calculated data in terms of performance?
It seems to be the best approach at the complexity level, but we don't know if performance will be an issue in the future.

Hi @unairoldan, Did you go through the overview and other specifications documents on the materialized view ? Have a look at these documents and check if they comply with all your requirements regarding performance or not. Let me know if this helped you or not.

I don't recommend using stored procedures since it's almost impossible to maintain when they scale. Instead, if you use an orchestrator or a transformation library, your life would be much easier.

@SabriKaragönen do you have an example of these tools? Really interesting, as I assumed to do it using stored procedures

You can use dbt, sqlmesh, bruin or any other data transformation library. I'm actively developing bruin, so if you have any question, I'm happy to help.

if the question as just about performance, yes materialized view would be much faster than stored procedure.
materialized Views:

you will pay for table storage + view Storage. so if you have huge data as view's output cost might go up. however, your compute cost/query cost would be very low.
also, refresh is automatic, or can be configured.

Stored Procedure
you will only pay for the table storage cost. however, you query/compute cost would be much more than materialized views.
